how to display a pie chart to indicate Checkbox statistics hierarchy
I have installed org-modern in my windows PC, but the Task list progress bar is not displayed like the Circular PIE as shown in the following screenshot. The source of the screenshot is the org-modern github repo readme file.
Is there something else I need to install or change?
Below is the cropped up image of the PIE I'm mentioning for more clarity:


The screenshot does not show pie charts and there is no mention of pie charts either in the README or in org-modern.el. What makes you think that the package is capable of doing pie charts? It's not even clear how a Task list progress bar would be displayed as a pie chart.

I added a cropped screenshot for more clarity. But for reference - I did not mean a PIE Chart. I mean the % completion indicator

I suspect the author uses some org-pretty-entity to change the opening square bracket to the circle with upper right quadrant black Unicode character (#x25d4). Please open an issue at the GitHub site and ask about that (and, if my guess is correct, please ask him to update the instructions on how to render the example properly).
